# Is $q$ allowed to assume any real value in a trigonometric equation?

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry, inverse-function

Suppose $f_q(x) = \sin^q x$. Next, we compute the inverse of $f_q(x)$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
               y &= \sin^q x \\
         y^{1/q} &= \sin x   \\
\arcsin{y^{1/q}} &= x        \\
\end{aligned}
$$
After exchanging $x$ and $y$ in the most recent equation, we obtain:
$$
y = f_q^{-1}(x) = \arcsin(x^{1/q}).
$$
Now, if we derivate $f_q^{-1}(x)$, we obtain:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{d}{dx} f_q^{-1}(x) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - x^{2/q}}} \frac{d}{dx} x^{1/q} \\
                         &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - x^{2/q}}} \frac{x^{1/q}}{qx}   \\
                         &= \frac{1}{qx^{1 - 1/q}\sqrt{1 - x^{2/q}}}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Now, we need the derivative of $\sin^q x$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
f'_q(x) &= \frac{d}{dx} \sin^q x \\
      &= q \sin^{q - 1} x \cos x.
\end{aligned}.
$$
Since we know from the calculus books that
$$
\frac{d}{dx} f_q^{-1}(x) = \frac{1}{f'_q(f_q^{-1}(x))},
$$
we must have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{\underbrace{qx^{1 - 1/q}}_{\alpha}\sqrt{1 - x^{2/q}}} &= \frac{1}{q\sin^{q-1}(\arcsin(x^{1/q})) \cos(\arcsin(x^{1/q}))} \\
             &= \frac{1}{\underbrace{qx^{1 - 1/q}}_{\alpha}\cos(\arcsin(x^{1/q}))},
\end{aligned}
$$
which leads to
$$
I_q(x) = \cos(\arcsin(x^{1/q})) = \sqrt{1 - x^{2/q}}.
$$
Exchanging $1/q$ with $q$ in $I_q(x)$ leads us to the desired identity
$$
\cos(\arcsin(x^q)) = \sqrt{1 - x^{2q}}.
$$

Now, my question is: will this work with any $q \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: It's definetly not going to work for even $q$, since $\sin^q x$ has no inverse for those values of $q$.

Comment: Since $\cos(\arcsin(y))=\sqrt{1-y^2}$ holds for any $y\in[-1,1]$, it follows, by taking $y=x^q$, that $\cos(\arcsin(x^q))=\sqrt{1-x^{2q}}$ holds for any $x\in[0,1]$ and any $q\in\mathbb R$. It might also holds for $x\in[-1,0)$ if $x^q$ makes sense, for instance $q\in\mathbb Z$.
You have a long and complicated proof that might make some extra assumptions (such as $q\ne0$), but the final result clearly holds.